# How do I match everything except matched value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dJ8zN3/3):

```
/(\[.*?\])/g
```

Now I want to change that regex to matches everything except current-matches. How can I do that?

**For example:**

Current regex:

```
   here is some text [anything123][/21something] and here is too [sometext][/afewtext] and here

//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I want this:

```
   here is some text [anything123][/21something] and here is too [sometext][/afewtext] and here
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Just use `replace` to replace the matches. `str.replace(/(\[.*?\])/g, '')`

Comment: @Tushar I want to know is there any approach to match everything except pattern in regex?

Comment: I would follow Tushar's suggestion using replace, that's what I was going to say.

Comment: [`\[[^\]]+\](?:^|\s)([\w']+)(?!\])\b|(?:^|\s)([\w']+)(?!\])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gU1nY6/2). See [Javascript Regex for all words not between certain characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448173/javascript-regex-for-all-words-not-between-certain-characters)

Comment: `text.split(/\[.*?\]/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match what's inside or capture what's outside <sup>[the trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)</sup>

```
\[.*?\]|([^[]+)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gU1nY6/1)

**Demo:**

```js
var str = 'here is some text [anything123][/21something] and here is too [sometext][/afewtext] and here';

var regex = /\[.*?\]|([^[]+)/g;
var res = '';

// Do this until there is a match
while(m = regex.exec(str)) {
    // If first captured group present
    if(m[1]) {
        // Append match to the result string
        res += m[1];
    }
}

console.log(res);
document.body.innerHTML = res; // For DEMO purpose only
```

Comment: @stack This does the same thing. You just need to get the first captured group and join them.

Comment: @Tushar Yeah I know the content of `$1` is exactly what I need. btw, I can do that exactly as you said *(using `.replace()`)*, But to be honest, I want to know how can I do that using lookahead `(?!)`? *(Because I saw an approach using lookahead somewhere)*

Comment: @Tushar Thank you .. yes it works ... But I think I cannot tell you what I want exactly .. `:-)` !! All I want to know is: *how do I define a regex to matches everthing except its pattern (pure regex)*

Comment: @stack [you want this](https://regex101.com/r/nT7nV0/1) but this does not work in JS regex :p

Comment: @stack Because that are [PCRE verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs). [You could try like this with lookaheads](https://regex101.com/r/vE1iU2/1) but this is expensive and more prown to fail.